# Using Rolle's theorem to deduce a property of repeated roots

Tags: calculus, functions

I've been trying for a while now to figure out how to use Rolle's theorem to show that if $x_1$ is a repeated root of the equation $f(x)=0$, then $x_1$ is also a root of the equation $f '(x)=0$. Now, this can easily be shown to be the case by simply taking the first derivative of $f(x)$ written in a form $A((x-x1)^m)*...$ where m is multiplicity of the root $x_1$ as it is obvious that in every term of the derivative, $(x-x_1)$ would show, so $x_1$ is its root. But this wouldn't involve using Rolle's theorem.

You can find a version of this problem on the page 138 of the book "Foundation Mathematics for the Physical Sciences"by K.F. Riley and M.P.Hobson here:http://books.google.rs/books?id=cIBXYz3jabUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false. 
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks :)

Comment: I do not see how Rolle's theorem will relate to repeated zeroes. For example, $f(x)=x^3$ has a repeated root but there are no two distinct points $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$. So Rolle's theorem could not be applied.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: I thought the term "repeated roots" was used only with polynomials.

Comment: Well, x1=repeated root of f(x)-> x1=root of f '(x) is true for any function with repeated roots so I guess the idea is to show it using theorem for general case. Ofcourse, my comment for deducing it from the form of derivative directly would have to be modified in order to apply if the function is not polynomial.

Comment: @Stefan, I am not sure about the convention for the use of the expression. I would be glad if someone could solve it for polynomials only too :)

Comment: @Storyteller011 : please see genepeer's comment.  That function is injective so Rolle's Theorem cannot apply at all.

Comment: One of the things that puzzled me in this was the thought of the functions like f(x)=(x-a)^m where m is odd. I thought I might have been missing something but I guess the claim that this can be done by using Rolle is a mistake. Thanks a lot, mathematicians :) Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Page 138 is not included in the Google excerpt.  I'm going to guess that the intent of the authors is to apply Rolle's Theorem in this way:

If $g(x)$ is differentiable on $(x_1 , x_2)$ with $x_1$ and $x_2$ being zeroes of the function, then there is a value $x = c$ in this interval for which $g'(c) = 0$.  We can imagine modifying $g$ , for instance, by shifting it vertically, so that the two zeroes "draw closer together"; $c$ remains in the interval between them.  In the limit, as $x_2$ approaches $x_1$ (and the function $g$ going over to our $f$), so does $c$ ; thus, we would have $x_1$ as a "repeated zero" with $f'(x_1) = 0 $ .

Maybe you don't like this argument, but I suspect that's what they're doing...

Comment: Thanks for the input, Reckless. I guess something like that is meant by the problem formulation. Something similar came to my mind but the problem with the idea is that it would only work for roots with double multiplicity. If by "repeated" what is actually meant is "double", that would work, I guess. PS. Page 138 is included in the google excerpt on my screen. It might be that google excerpts are not allways displaying the same pages. I know that happens with amazon.com excerpts. Try reloading the excerpt few times. Cheers!